# Characteristics of parallel parabola (offset curve) and the formula to find the equation

Tags: functions

[image]

What are the characteristics of parallel parabola? And is there any formula to find the equation of parallel parabola if we know the equation of one parabola?

Comment: What do you mean? Like would $x^2$ and $x^2+1$ be parallel? how about $x^2$ and $(x-1)^2$

Comment: Imagine like two parabola that some what seem to be concentric and have equal width , consider the image I am going to attach. Also , after few research I am kind of sure of the fact that there can only be a curve parallel to parabola so I might want to change the question to curve parallel to parabola.

Comment: Do you mean that a parallel curve at distance $d$ to a given curve is obtain by "dilation", i.e., by considering each point of the curve as the center of a circle with radius $d$ and considering the limit curve of these circles ? (as in optics using Huygens method)

Comment: You may have a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2754209/660).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(see graphics below obtained with Geogebra, using formulas in the text).

Preliminary remark: The keyword "parallel curve" is ambiguous ; you see it replaced by "offset curve" in many works.

If a curve is defined parametrically by $X=\binom{x=x(t)}{y=y(t)}$, a tangent vector is $T=\binom{x'(t)}{y'(t)}$ (speed vector); we can take as normal vector $N=\binom{ \ \ y'(t)}{-x'(t)}$ (check that the dot product $N \bullet T$ is 0), and the **unit norm normal vector** is $N/\|N\|=\binom{y'(t)/\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}}{-x'(t)/\sqrt{x'^2(t)+y'^2(t)}},$ with a certain orientation (outwards or inwards with respect to the initial curve.)

Thus, if you want to be at distance $a$ from the initial curve, you proceed from the generic point by making a step of length $a$ in the direction of vector  $N/\|N\|$ giving the parametric representation that can found as well in the Wikipedia article on [parallel and offset curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve):

$$\tag{1}\left\{\begin{aligned}X&=x+a{\frac {y'}{\sqrt {{x'}^{2}+{y'}^{2}}}}\\Y&=y-a{\frac {x'}{\sqrt {{x'}^{2}+{y'}^{2}}}}.\end{aligned}\right.$$

Let us take the case of the standard parabola $y=x^2$ with parametrization $x=t, \ y=t^2$; we get: $x'=1, \ y'=2t$, yielding

$$\tag{2}\left\{\begin{aligned}X&=t+\frac {2at}{\sqrt {1+4t^2}}\\Y&=t^2-{\frac {a}{\sqrt {1+4t^2}}}.\end{aligned}\right.$$

which is a parametric representation that allows to draw any parallel curve to the initial parabola. According to the sign of $a$, these curves will be external or internal to the parabola (I understand you are interested in external curves).

One can, using a CAS (Mathematica in my case), eliminate $t$ between the 2 expressions above ; one gets a 12th degree implicit equation that can be expressed as the product of two 6th degree factors in variables $X,Y$:

$$\left( 9\,a^2 - 24\,a^4 + 16\,a^6 - 92\,a^2\,X^2 - 
    48\,a^4\,X^2 - 9\,X^4 + 48\,a^2\,X^4 - 16\,X^6 + 24\,a^2\,Y - 
    32\,a^4\,Y + 18\,X^2\,Y + 24\,a^2\,X^2\,Y + 8\,X^4\,Y - 
    9\,Y^2 + 40\,a^2\,Y^2 - 16\,a^4\,Y^2 + 32\,X^2\,Y^2 + 
    32\,a^2\,X^2\,Y^2 - 16\,X^4\,Y^2 - 24\,Y^3 + 32\,a^2\,Y^3 + 
    32\,X^2\,Y^3 - 16\,Y^4 \right) \,
  \left( a^2 + 8\,a^4 + 16\,a^6 + 20\,a^2\,X^2 - 48\,a^4\,X^2 - 
    X^4 + 48\,a^2\,X^4 - 16\,X^6 - 8\,a^2\,Y - 32\,a^4\,Y + 
    2\,X^2\,Y - 8\,a^2\,X^2\,Y + 40\,X^4\,Y - Y^2 + 8\,a^2\,Y^2 - 
    16\,a^4\,Y^2 - 32\,X^2\,Y^2 + 32\,a^2\,X^2\,Y^2 - 
    16\,X^4\,Y^2 + 8\,Y^3 + 32\,a^2\,Y^3 + 32\,X^2\,Y^3 - 16\,Y^4
    \right)=0$$

(please note that $a$ is always present with an even exponent).

One of the factors accounts for the external curve at distance $a$, the other for the internal curve at distance $a$. These expressions are untractable for practical applications.

These offset curves being polynomials with degree 6, they aren't conic curves (2nd degree polynomials), even if they look for example like parabolas when they are close to the "mother curve" (but with an increasingly circular aspect at the bottom).

It is to be noted that *internal* parallel curves can have a spike.

The second figure gives a different view: the offset curves are implicitly realized as "envelopes" of circles (think to the parabola as an atoll and the inside of the circles as "territorial waters" within a same distance).

[image]

[image]

Remark: As @WimC remarked, one can separate the
inside and outside offset curves, giving the example of parabola $x=y^2$ for which the inside offset curve at distance $1$ has the following 6th degree equation
$$16 x^4 - 32 x^3 y^2 - 40 x^3 + 16 x^2 y^4 + 9 x^2 - 40 x y^4 + 6 x y^2 +40 x + 16 y^6 - 47 y^4 + 28 y^2 - 25 = 0 $$

Comment: Thank you Jean , I think I got it :)

Comment: In fact a *single* 6th degree curve accounts for *both* parts (inside and outside).

Comment: @WimC Thanks for your very interesting comment. Do you have a reference ?

Comment: See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=16+x%5E4+-+32+x%5E3+y%5E2+-+40+x%5E3+%2B+16+x%5E2+y%5E4+%2B+9+x%5E2+-+40+x+y%5E4+%2B+6+x+y%5E2+%2B40+x+%2B+16+y%5E6+-+47+y%5E4+%2B+28+y%5E2+-+25+%3D+0) for an offset $1$ curve to $x=y^2$ for example.

Comment: Want I meant to say is that your paragraph “One of the factors …” is false. Only one factor (of degree six) accounts for *both* offset curves (internal and external). My guess is that you used something like a resultant of two polynomials (one in $x$ and $t$, the other in $y$ and $t$). But then you’ll see that one of the factors represents a totally different curve and not an offset curve. This is because you lose the sign correlation between the square roots that appear in your original parameterisation.

Comment: @WimC Thanks for this very important rectification, 4 years later. As soon as I have enough time, I will make an important "edit" to this answer along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

This might answer your question.

In the case of:

$y = a x^2$

Where:

$x$ = coordinate for point on the Parabola

$y$ = coordinate for point on the Parabola

$a$ = dilation coefficient of the Parabola

$X_d$ = coordinate for point displaced normal to a tangent of the Parabola

$Y_d$ = coordinate for point displaced normal to a tangent of the Parabola

$d$ = displaced amount

Then:

$X_d = x ± \frac{2dx}{2(\sqrt{.25a^2+x^2})}$

$Y_d = y ± \frac{.5da}{\sqrt{.25a^2+x^2}}$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Say you have a parabola of the form $ax^2+bx+c$.

Another parabola is parallel if it is of the form $ax^2+bx+k$, where $k$ is a constant that is not equal to $c$.

If $k=c$, then the parabolas would be  identical.

Comment: if a , b in both case are identical an k =c, parabola will form a same graph, thus, one cannot be parallel to the other.

Comment: I don't think that it is the meaning the OP gives to "parallel".

Comment: but they said the same width...  @JeanMarie what do they mean? i'm a bit confused too

Comment: Yes but it depends what you mean by width... If you look at the picture given, there is no such thing as a constant vertical shift coefficient (this "shift" would be smaller in $x=0$ that in $x=5$). See the question I have asked in a comment.

Comment: I am pretty sure I was wrong about the width thingy , okay so I am supposing there is a parabola lets take : ax^2 , so , I need to find the equation of curve that is parallel to ax^2.