# Convex set that cannot be approximated by a polygon

Tags: convex-analysis, polygons

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, show that there exist no polygon containing the set $C = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y \geq x^2\}$ and included in $C + B(0,1)$ where $B(0,1)$ is the open unit ball.

Intuitively, we could say that we can't find a finite number of affine inequalities containing the parabola $C$ and included in a parabola that includes $C + B(0,1)$. However I struggle to formalize it. Thanks.

Comment: A polyhedron is $3$-dimensional. The $2$-dimensional word is _polygon_ (and for $4$ or more dimensions, it's _polytope_).

Comment: Also, I don't understand the question: $C$ is unbounded, so it obviously can't be contained in a polygon.

Comment: I have corrested "polyhedron" into "polygon". Is your sum a Minkowski sum which means that the second set is a so-called **dilated set** of $C$. But beware, the dilated set of a parabola isn't a parabola.

Comment: @JeanMarie: Well, of course the dilated set isn't a parabola. Did you mean to say that the two _boundaries_ of the dilated set are not parabolas?

Comment: @TonyK You are right, I was meaning the dilated set of $C$, i.e. the dilated set of the interior of the parabola looks to have a parabolic border but it is not the case (if I remember well, it has a 8th degree parametric polynomial).

Comment: @TonyK Here is an answer of mine about the offset curve (morphological dilation) of a parabola: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2315746. It is in fact a 6th degree curve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is going to depend on what counts as a "polygon".

- If a "polygon" has its most traditional meaning of a closed piecewise-linear curve, then all polygons are bounded and cannot contain an unbounded such as $C$.
- If a "polygon" is any simple piecewise-linear curve with only finitely many vertices, so it can be open ending in two rays extending to $\infty$ (usually this is called a "polygonal curve", not a "polygon"). Then it is a matter of showing that the two end-rays must either intersect $y = x^2$ or eventually deviate from it by a distance of more than $1$. This is a matter of showing that $y = x^2$ deviates from linear by more than that, no matter how far out you go.
- If a "polygon" is a piecewise-linear curve that can have infinitely many vertices, then the statement is false. One can easily approximate $y=x^2$ to any accuracy with infinitely many line segments.

I have to assume that you must mean the second case, since the first is trivial and the third is false. If you can clarify, then I or someone else can share more details on it.

Comment: I originally used the word *polyhedron* not *polygon* since the definition I have of *polyhedron* is: a subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which can be written as an intersection of finitely many closed halspaces. I don't think it implies that such a set is bounded (since a dsubspace e.g. verifies this definition). 

So what I had in mind was the description you gave in the second case. As you rightly say, showing that the two end-rays intersect $y=x^2$ seems to be the way to get to the conclusion. Thanks!

Comment: @vtg - the problem is *polyhedron* is a word with a well-known meaning, from which your meaning differs in 3 particulars: the canonical "polyhedron" (1) is 3-dimensional (2) is bounded (3) need not be convex. If you give a different meaning to a canonical word, you need to indicate that. For 3D, you could have just called it a "hyper-polyhedron", a common indicator that a 3D name is being used in other dimensions. But since 2D hyper-polyhedra already have a well-known name, "polygons", better to use that. And for convexity - never rely on tags to provide information - that isn't their purpose.

Comment: '@Paul Sinclair  thanks for clarifying.

I guess I mistook *polyhedral* and *polyhedron*.  

The definition of *polyhedral* is given as: A set is said to be *polyhedral* if it is nonempty and it is
the intersection of a finite number of halfspaces, i.e., if it has the form:

$\left\{ x \, \mid  a_j^Tx \leq b_j, \: j=1,\dots,r \right\}$  

where $a_1, \dots , a_r$ and $b_1, \dots , b_r$ are some vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and scalars, respectively.

And the polyhedral is convex as an intersection of halfspaces (which are convex).

Comment: *Polyhedral* is just the adjective form of polyhedron. Note that the definition says the set "is polyhedral", not "is a polyhedral", just as you might say "the house is red", but not "the house is a red". The definition may be specific to this book, or may be common in convex-analysis, but it is not common to mathematics at large, where "polyhedral" is still generally used to describe bounded 3D objects that may not be convex. It is okay to use this terminology, but you need to explain it when talking to a general audience, or expect they will misunderstand.