# How do I Find an Explicit Equation With Constant Distance to a Parabola?

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have a side-opening parabola $y² = a (x + b)$, or $f(x) = ±\sqrt{a (x + b)}$. I want to find the equations which are, at all points, exactly $d$ units away from the parabola, one inside the parabola and one outside the parabola. I can find individual points at the specified distance from a given point on the parabola, but I'm not sure how to convert those points into equations in the form of $y = g(x)$ and $y = h(x)$.

I know that the shortest distance between a point on the parabola $(X_1, f(X_1))$ and a point on the desired equation $(X_2, g(X_2))$ will be measured on the line normal to the parabola at that point, and the set of all points at a certain distance to a given point is a circle, so I've been working under the assumption that I need to find the two points that are the intersections of the normal line and a circle of radius $d$ at a given value of $X_1$, and then figure out the equations those points travel along. For simplicity, I will focus on the bottom half of the parabola, or $f(x) = -\sqrt{a (x + b)}$

The normal line at a point is perpendicular to the tangent line at that point. The slope of the tangent line is the derivative of the parabola $m_t = -\frac{1} {2} \sqrt{\frac{a} {b + X}}$, so the normal line has a slope that is the negative inverse of that, $m_n = \frac{2} {\sqrt{\frac{a} {b + X}}}$. Plugging this into the point-slope form of a line, we get $y = \frac{2} {\sqrt{\frac{a} {b + X}}} (x - X_1) + f(X_1)$, which expands to $y = \sqrt{\frac{b + X_1} {a}} (a - 2 (x - X_1))$, giving us the equation for the normal line at a given $X_1$ value.

The equation for a circle with radius $d$ centered on the point $(h, k)$ is $(x - h)² + (y - k)² = d²$. Plugging in the values from my parabola and solving for $y$ we get $y = ±\sqrt{d² - (x - X_1)²} - \sqrt{a (X_1 + b)}$.

Setting the equation for the normal line and the equation for the circle equal to each other and solving for $x$, we get $x = X_1 ± d \sqrt{\frac{a} {a + 4 (b + X_1)}}$. Plugging that pair of $x$ values into the equation for the normal line to find the matching $y$ values, we get the points
$$\left(X_1 + d \sqrt{\frac{a} {a + 4 (b + X_1)}}, -\sqrt{\frac{b + X_1} {a}} \left(a - 2 d \sqrt{\frac{a} {a + 4 (b + X_1)}}\right)\right)$$

and

$$\left(X_1 - d \sqrt{\frac{a} {a + 4 (b + X_1)}}, -\sqrt{\frac{b + X_1} {a}} \left(a + 2 d \sqrt{\frac{a} {a + 4 (b + X_1)}}\right)\right)$$

These are the points located $d$ units away from the parabola at the point $(X_1, f(X_1))$.

However, I can't figure out how to proceed from here and turn these points, effectively a pair of parametric equations with parameter $X_1$, into explicit equations analogous to $y² = a (x + b)$ or $f(x) = ±\sqrt{a (x + b)}$. Is this even possible?

Comment: It is possible, e.g. by using a Gröbner basis technique, to find the polynomial equation for the offset curve, but it is not pleasant. It is a curve of degree six.

Comment: See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=groebnerbasis%5B%7Bx-y%5E2%2C+%28X-x%29%5E2%2B%28Y-y%29%5E2-d%5E2%2C+%28X-x%29+2+y+%2B+%28Y+-+y%29+%7D%2C+%7Bx%2Cy%2CX%2CY%7D%5D) for an example to find the equation for the curve at distance $d$ from $x=y^2$. It is the first entry in the result.

Comment: It is rather difficult-to-manage 6th degree polynomial curves called "offset curves". See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2315746)